# Firefox closes unexpectedly and appears this error

Tags: firefox

I am running the Selenium IDE with Firefox in Linux and after a while Firefox closes unexpectedly and with the following error:

> [NPAPI 1421] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /build/firefox-DdKYuG/firefox-52.0.2+build1/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2143
>   Kille

in the console. What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

NPAPI is related to java plugin in firefox. But all java plugin will be deactivated for every forefox verion upper to firefox 52.
That the only think I can find with the informations you provided ! what's your firefox version ?

Comment: my version is 54.0 (64-bit) "http://i.imgur.com/63xWS74.png" Then I should switch to an older version and update java, excuse my english.